# How to create has_many and belong_to one associations in Rails using a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I have the following models:`List` that has (name and user_id fields) and `User`.

Each list has many users. And each list belong to ONE user.

I created `client_lists` table:

```
class CreateClientListsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :client_lists do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :list_id
    end
    add_index :client_lists, :user_id
    add_index :client_lists, :list_id
  end
end
```

Now for the first relationship it's easy to say that a list belong to a user and that a user has many lists:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates  :user, :presence => true
end
```

And

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Anyways, how am I supposed to find the list of clients through client_lists table?

I added HABTM relationship for List

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients, :join_table => "client_lists", :foreign_key => "user_id"
end
```

Then tried `List.first.clients` and got the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant List::Client
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to create `ClientLists` model:

```
class ClientLists < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :list
end
```

Then adding the following to List model:

```
  has_many :client_lists, :class_name => "ClientLists", :foreign_key => "list_id"
  has_many :clients, through: :client_lists, source: :user
```